# What are the benefits and dangers of adding methods to Object.prototype in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know this was a contentious issue five years ago, but I'm wondering if things have changed for today's JavaScript. Are there any real world examples of a major modern library being incompatible with extending `Object.prototype`?

I'm not interested in hypothetical "someone may write bad `for in` iteration code in a library that you want to use, maybe, in the future, and then you might get a weird bug"

Comment: There's a nice discussion about this on [Object.prototype is erlaubt](http://www.thomasfrank.se/object_prototype_is_erlaubt.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are there any real world examples of a major modern library being incompatible with extending Object.prototype?

Yes, I remember problems with jQuery, -which is one of the *less intrusive* libraries- for example:

- [I tried to prototype a length() method to Object and broke jQuery – how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638450/i-tried-to-prototype-a-length-method-to-object-and-broke-jquery-how)

Another case that I remember is that someone added a `load` function to the `Object.prototype` object, and it caused problems with the `$().load` event:

```
// DON'T DO THIS ! :)
Object.prototype.load = function () {};

​$(window).load(function () {
  alert('load event'); // never fired
});​
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/iwude4/edit).

Augmenting the `Object.prototype` object in that way is never recommended, because those properties will be inherited by a great number of objects -even also by some host objects-, and as you know, the primary concern is that they will be enumerated by the `for-in` statement.

In ECMAScript 5, now a safer way exist, because we can now declare non-enumerable properties, for example:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', { value: 'bar' });
```

In the property descriptor -`{ value: 'bar' }`- we can specify property attributes, in the case of *Value Properties* as in the above example, we can specify the `writable` attribute, and the common `configurable` attribute (determines if a property can be re-configured -attribute changes- or deleted.

And we have also the `enumerable` attribute, which determines if the property will be enumerated by the `for-in` statement.

If we don't specify the attributes, they are `false` by default, the descriptor will look like:

```
{
  value: 'bar',
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about jQuery not working correctly in all cases when Object.prototype is extended. I have read that they are planning to get it to interact nicely at some point in the future. I suppose that for now it's still too early to be extending Object.prototype without very careful consideration.

Comment: Soooo for extra info; I put 2 extensions within the object prototype (forEach and getLength) and it breaks most of google's scripts.