# Build js function within jQuery SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've created a new js function like this

```
Object.prototype.testFn = function(){
    s=this;
    alert(s);
    }
a='word';           
a.testFn();
```

i'ts working as well, but, when i use jQuery sdk, then i call jQuery live, my testFn function is called repeatedly. and sometimes, the whole script is not working...

Comment: The solution is simple: Don't extend `Object.prototype`. It breaks jQuery and is bad style anyway.

Comment: @Felix Kling: so, hows the way to build a js function within jQuery sdk?

Comment: Can't you just create a global function with `function testFn() {}`?

Comment: @AfrigAminuddin: Not really sure what you mean with that. Just define your functions normally. jQuery is only JavaScript. Or do you want to create a plugin for jQuery? A function that can be called on a jQuery object, like `$('selector').yourFunction()` ? Please clarify.

Comment: @Dysaster:ya, it can be... but, i want to build a function like jQuery plugin does...

Comment: @Felix Kling: ya you're right, i will...

Comment: not sure what exactly you would like to achieve with this function. Would be helpful to answer if you could elaborate the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment, extending `Object.prototype` [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832617/what-are-the-benefits-and-dangers-of-adding-methods-to-object-prototype-in-javasc). It most likely will break other libraries.

There is no special way to define functions when you are using jQuery. It is simply:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    // manipulate obj
}
```

---

But as you mention jQuery, mayby you want to create a plugin, the basic structure is:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

};
```

You have to extend `jQuery.fn`.

How to create a plugin is very well explained in the [***Plugins/Authoring***](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) tutorial.

Comment: `this` on this function refers to DOM Object, and the object is must be the jQuery object, unlike my function above, `this` refers to `a` object as a string

Comment: If you are using jQuery and want to define your own function to manipulate DOM Objects in some way I definitely recommend extending jQuery as explained above. You get all the benefit from Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) and the other jQuery perks.

Comment: @EMMERICH: what should i do when the object is not DOM object, my `a` object is a string, i want to manipulate this string...

Comment: @AfrigAminuddin: Well, I don't really know what you want. If you want to extend every object, then it is not related to jQuery at all and I wonder why you mention it. That you should not extend `Object.prototype` still holds. Define a function instead which accepts the object as first argument.