# The global object in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I run this code in chrome:

```
for(var i in window){console.log(i)}
```

I get a lot of properties as shown below.

But if I run this code:

```
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty("parseInt"))
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty("undefined"))
```

I get `true` for both.

How is it possible that `.hasOwnProperty()` returns `true`, yet it doesn't show up in the list of properties produced by the `for-in` loop?

Result from loop:

```
top VM1531:2
window VM1531:2
location VM1531:2
external VM1531:2
chrome VM1531:2
document VM1531:2
getInnerFunction VM1531:2
theInnerFunction VM1531:2
__commandLineAPI VM1531:2
i VM1531:2
speechSynthesis VM1531:2
localStorage VM1531:2
sessionStorage VM1531:2
applicationCache VM1531:2
webkitStorageInfo VM1531:2
indexedDB VM1531:2
webkitIndexedDB VM1531:2
crypto VM1531:2
CSS VM1531:2
performance VM1531:2
console VM1531:2
devicePixelRatio VM1531:2
styleMedia VM1531:2
parent VM1531:2
opener VM1531:2
frames VM1531:2
self VM1531:2
defaultstatus VM1531:2
defaultStatus VM1531:2
status VM1531:2
name VM1531:2
length VM1531:2
closed VM1531:2
pageYOffset VM1531:2
pageXOffset VM1531:2
scrollY VM1531:2
scrollX VM1531:2
screenTop VM1531:2
screenLeft VM1531:2
screenY VM1531:2
screenX VM1531:2
innerWidth VM1531:2
innerHeight VM1531:2
outerWidth VM1531:2
outerHeight VM1531:2
offscreenBuffering VM1531:2
frameElement VM1531:2
clientInformation VM1531:2
navigator VM1531:2
toolbar VM1531:2
statusbar VM1531:2
scrollbars VM1531:2
personalbar VM1531:2
menubar VM1531:2
locationbar VM1531:2
history VM1531:2
screen VM1531:2
postMessage VM1531:2
close VM1531:2
blur VM1531:2
focus VM1531:2
ondeviceorientation VM1531:2
ondevicemotion VM1531:2
onautocompleteerror VM1531:2
onautocomplete VM1531:2
onunload VM1531:2
onstorage VM1531:2
onpopstate VM1531:2
onpageshow VM1531:2
onpagehide VM1531:2
ononline VM1531:2
onoffline VM1531:2
onmessage VM1531:2
onhashchange VM1531:2
onbeforeunload VM1531:2
onwaiting VM1531:2
onvolumechange VM1531:2
ontoggle VM1531:2
ontimeupdate VM1531:2
onsuspend VM1531:2
onsubmit VM1531:2
onstalled VM1531:2
onshow VM1531:2
onselect VM1531:2
onseeking VM1531:2
onseeked VM1531:2
onscroll VM1531:2
onresize VM1531:2
onreset VM1531:2
onratechange VM1531:2
onprogress VM1531:2
onplaying VM1531:2
onplay VM1531:2
onpause VM1531:2
onmousewheel VM1531:2
onmouseup VM1531:2
onmouseover VM1531:2
onmouseout VM1531:2
onmousemove VM1531:2
onmouseleave VM1531:2
onmouseenter VM1531:2
onmousedown VM1531:2
onloadstart VM1531:2
onloadedmetadata VM1531:2
onloadeddata VM1531:2
onload VM1531:2
onkeyup VM1531:2
onkeypress VM1531:2
onkeydown VM1531:2
oninvalid VM1531:2
oninput VM1531:2
onfocus VM1531:2
onerror VM1531:2
onended VM1531:2
onemptied VM1531:2
ondurationchange VM1531:2
ondrop VM1531:2
ondragstart VM1531:2
ondragover VM1531:2
ondragleave VM1531:2
ondragenter VM1531:2
ondragend VM1531:2
ondrag VM1531:2
ondblclick VM1531:2
oncuechange VM1531:2
oncontextmenu VM1531:2
onclose VM1531:2
onclick VM1531:2
onchange VM1531:2
oncanplaythrough VM1531:2
oncanplay VM1531:2
oncancel VM1531:2
onblur VM1531:2
onabort VM1531:2
onwheel VM1531:2
onwebkittransitionend VM1531:2
onwebkitanimationstart VM1531:2
onwebkitanimationiteration VM1531:2
onwebkitanimationend VM1531:2
ontransitionend VM1531:2
onsearch VM1531:2
getSelection VM1531:2
print VM1531:2
stop VM1531:2
open VM1531:2
alert VM1531:2
confirm VM1531:2
prompt VM1531:2
find VM1531:2
scrollBy VM1531:2
scrollTo VM1531:2
scroll VM1531:2
moveBy VM1531:2
moveTo VM1531:2
resizeBy VM1531:2
resizeTo VM1531:2
matchMedia VM1531:2
getComputedStyle VM1531:2
getMatchedCSSRules VM1531:2
webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode VM1531:2
webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage VM1531:2
requestAnimationFrame VM1531:2
cancelAnimationFrame VM1531:2
webkitRequestAnimationFrame VM1531:2
webkitCancelAnimationFrame VM1531:2
webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame VM1531:2
captureEvents VM1531:2
releaseEvents VM1531:2
btoa VM1531:2
atob VM1531:2
setTimeout VM1531:2
clearTimeout VM1531:2
setInterval VM1531:2
clearInterval VM1531:2
TEMPORARY VM1531:2
PERSISTENT VM1531:2
showModalDialog VM1531:2
webkitRequestFileSystem VM1531:2
webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL VM1531:2
openDatabase VM1531:2
addEventListener VM1531:2
removeEventListener VM1531:2
dispatchEvent
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? They're both global symbols; where else would they be?

Comment: Oh - a `for ... in` loop does not iterate over *all* properties, just the ones marked as iterable.

Comment: @Pointy. I you are right I guess. I thought it was all properties. Write you answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Object properties can be hidden from iteration mechanisms by marking them as not being "enumerable":

```
var foo = { a: "Hello", b: "World" };
Object.defineProperty(foo, "c", { value: "where am I?" });
```

By default, properties defined with `defineProperty()` are *not* enumerable, so if you ran a `for ... in` loop over object "foo" you wouldn't see "c".

Of course, the global object is something with all sorts of magic properties, but the basic "enumerable" flag still applies. As to *why* exactly "parseInt" and "undefined" are not enumerable, I have no insight.

*edit* — cookie monster points out in a comment that the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` function *will* return the names of non-enumerable properties. However `Object.keys()` will not. Thus you could use that difference to see whether an object has non-enumerable properties:

```
 function hasSneakyProperties(o) {
     return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).length !== Object.keys(o).length;
 }
```

I don't know why anybody would do that but there you go.

Comment: They're not enumerable [because the spec says so](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) of course. :P ("*Unless otherwise specified, the standard built-in properties of the global object have attributes `{[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}`*")

Comment: @apsillers ha ha yes I figured it was in the spec (though I didn't check); I meant the rationale about why they're not enumerable.

Comment: Worth noting that he could use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` to get the full list of own properties, and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "undefined")` to examine its settings.

Comment: This is worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean