# Object.getOwnPropertyNames()

Tags: javascript, object

when working with frameworks(in this case Phaser.js) I like to use the console and look for possible properties of Objects with

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject)
```

However, some properties wont show up in the console and I assume is due to not being "**Own**PropertyNames" of the object. Is there a way to still get them to show in the console?

I´m basically looking for something like

```
Object.getAllPropertyNames(myObject)
```

Could someone help me out? I´m new to JS :)

Comment: Look at `Object.keys`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Chrome's DevTools, you can view all properties of an object by calling `dir(myObject)`:

[image]

Comment: This is cool - thanks a lot! Could you explain me why the properties(on the bottom) are in a lighter blue? What does this mean? Are they inheritated?
 These properties wont show up when using 
    "Object.getOwnProperties(game.stage);"                                                           https://i.gyazo.com/18dd2063923cc159de46abb9f386832b.png

Comment: @Faizy What do you mean "in blue"? In the picture property keys are purple.

Comment: @Faizy Light-purple properties are [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)

Comment: @Faizy **Non-enumerable properties are not visible in for-loops:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn´t they still pop up using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`? It says "The Object.getOwnPropertyNames() method returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for ... in` loop to loop over all the properties. This will also loops over the "parent" properties.

```js
// example data
var o = { 
  a: "a1",
  b: "b1"
}

var parent = { 
  c: "c1",
  d: "d1"
}
// set parent, just for the example
Object.setPrototypeOf(o, parent);
  
// loop over all
for (key in o)
{
  console.log('prop "' + key + '" with value "' + o[key] + '"');
}
```

Nested example:

```js
var game =  {
  stage :{
    test1 : 'v1',
    test2 : 'v2'
    
  }
   
}

for (key in game.stage) 
 { console.log(key + '" with value "' + game.stage[key] + '"'); }
```

Comment: Thanks Julian. If I have the object "game" and it has the property "stage", how can I use the for ... in loop to get every property in/behind "game.stage"?

Comment: `for (key in game.stage) ...`

Comment: If I try it like this    `for (key in game.stage)
{
  console.log(key + '" with value "' + game.stage[key] + '"');
}`    the console returns "nothing"`...

Comment: added the `game.stage` example. Maybe the script is running to soon? (should run after DOM loaded)