# how to access correct tag through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a html page with a structure:

```
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>A</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>B</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>C</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>D</h3></div>
</div>
```

I have attached a hover event on the uppermost div with:

```
$(".row.sem").hover(function(){
//my code....
});
```

Now,when I hover on one of these divs,I want to access the inner content of only those h3 elements which are within my hovered div element.

For this,I tried:

```
var a = $(this).children(["h3"]);
 for(ei in ee){                
   console.log(ei);     
  }
```

But,this printed much more stuff like **fadein,fadeout,scroll...**.The **this** object does not contain the inner tags of the hovered div.

Please suggest what is wrong in this implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.children()` collects direct children elements while you're looking for `h3`. So you could use `.find()` method or even (more specific) `.children('.subject').children('h3')`.

```js
$(".row.sem").hover(function(){
  // mouse enter
  var a = $(this).find("h3");
  a.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
}, function(){
    // mouse leave
    console.clear();
    // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>A</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>B</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>C</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>D</h3></div>
</div>
```

see: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: can I restrict it to print only on first hover?It will print every time,which is not required.

Comment: yes, you could change `.hover()` by `.one('mouseenter')`. here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ruxv3axv/. also see: http://api.jquery.com/one/. I recommend you to deep into `.on()` and `.off()` which are very helpful.

Comment: there are some ways. when you do a loop you've an index so you can identify the div by its index. another workaround (much better to keep it clear) is that you can use html `data-*` attributes. example: https://jsfiddle.net/o68vt0nh/

Comment: yeah,I figured it out from your answer.Thanks.By mistake,my previous comment got deleted.

Comment: can you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748781/how-to-add-hierarchical-html-elements-through-jquery

Answer (score 2):

This will get the content of the `h3` child elements of the `.row.sem` elements. You needed to get all the children of the div you are hovering over. You can access and modify the html content of these children with `.html()` and I suggest you look into that method.

```js
$(".row.sem").hover(
  function() {
    console.log($(this).children().text());
  }, function (){}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>A</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>B</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>C</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>D</h3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Clear and simple.

```js
$(".row.sem").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("h3").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>A</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>B</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>C</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>D</h3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check MDN documentation [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) it says that it itarates over "enumerable properties".
Check this post also [enumarable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893752/6947248)

Check this out.

```js
$(".row.sem").hover(function(){

  // i am list of all headers nested inside element with class "row" and "sem"
  //  elements(array)
  var headers = $(this).find('h3');
   
   // console first element's html from the array.
   console.log($(headers[0]).html())
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>A</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>B</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row sem">
 <div class="subject"><h3>C</h3></div>
 <div class="subject"><h3>D</h3></div>
</div>
```