# What is the definition of an enumerable function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have read that an enumerable property is something that can be iterated over, so is an enumerable function a function that can also be iterated over, or, a function that performs the iteration?

Below is a reference to a Backbone article that mentions enumerable functions:

https://developers.supportbee.com/singlepageapp/introduction-to-backbone/

And the text reads

> Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

Comment: The term makes no sense. Where did you read it?

Comment: Have you tried this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893752/4133401

Comment: "*something that can be iterated over*" - not exactly. More like [something *that will show up* when the object is enumerated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

Comment: maybe an enumerable function is just an enumerable property that happens to be a function - because functions in javascript are so-called first-class

Comment: Most likely they were just referring to an enumerable property that holds a function

Comment: I have edited the question with a link to the site that mentions it.

Comment: I added the text from the link. Feel free to correct it if I reference the wrong section.