# Unexpected output from Object.assign

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

So I got a little surprised by:

```
Object.assign({}, Math)
```

Which returned an empty object. I was doing this to set up my own math module, that I could extend with my own custom functionality, so I thought it would be convenient to do:

```
Object.assign({}, Math, { 
  sqrt: <my-sqrt-implementation>, 
  add: <my-add-implementation >,
})
```

But I was surprised to find that the math entries were not included, why is that? In my console I get:

```
Object.assign({}, Math)
> {}
```

What went wrong, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties of `Math` are not [enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean). [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will copy only enumerable and own properties:

> The `Object.assign()` method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses `[[Get]]` on the source and `[[Set]]` on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` and `Object.defineProperty()` should be used instead.

Thus you should follow the suggestion, and use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)` to get a list of own property names, then `Object.defineProperty()` to assign them:

```
const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)
const myMath = {}
props.forEach(prop => {
    Object.defineProperty(myMath, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, prop))
})

myMath.sin(3.14)  // 0.00159265...
```

Of course, it is probably better to use prototypical inheritance (`Object.create`) here. I provide this code because it more closely matches the behavior of `Object.assign`, i.e. assignment.

Answer (score 3):

From : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object

`Math` properties aren't enumerable or own.

Example:

[image]

> How can this be fixed?

Use `Object.create` e.g.

```
var MyMath = Object.create(Math);
MyMath.sqrt = function () {
};
```

Comment: I believe the Math properties are *own* (e.g., Math.hasOwnProperty('abs') is true). You are correct that they are not enumerable.

Comment: If this is the case, then something like `var myMath = Object.assign(Object.create(Math), {...myMethods})` should work then. But its not working in my console.

Answer (score 0):

The properties and methods under the `Math` object are set up as `non-iterable`.  When `Object.assign` tries to copy them, they don't show up.

If you add your own property to the `Math` object, you'll see it is found and copied over.

`Object.create`, on the other hand, should do what you want.

```js
// You shouldn't ever really do this.
Math.testProperty = true;
var myMath = Object.assign({}, Math);

console.log(myMath.testProperty);
```