# Do not log symbols using util.inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-symbol

I have this object which has some symbols properties on it:

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  [Symbol(raw.json.bytes)]: 13,
  [Symbol(raw.json.str)]: '{"foo":"bar"}'
}
```

now, I added those symbol properties myself, so maybe I can change how I add them using Object.defineProperty. Is there some way to prevent logging the symbols either:

1. using an option to util.inspect(v, opts)
2. Or by using Object.defineProperty?

Either way I am using util.inspect() to stringify the object, and my preference is to pass it an option to not log non-enumerable properties or what not.

Comment: I tried using `util.inspect(v, {showHidden: false}))` and that didn't work, perhaps because the symbol properts are not hidden? But they are just added with `o[Symbol()] = 'x'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if the `showHidden` option is set to `false` (default) by using non-enumerable symbols.

To do this, define symbols the following way:

```js
Object.defineProperty(obj, symbol, {
  enumerable: false,  //that matters!
  configurable: true, //or false
  writable: true,     //or false
  value: value
})
```

Properties defined like this  (not necessarily symbols<sup>1</sup>) will not be included in `util.inspect` calls if the `showHidden` option is false.

---

<sup>1: Defining non-enumerable non-symbol properties has the side effect of skipping them when iterating over the keys/values of an object with `for..in` loops, `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()`. Read more [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) or [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17893718/8376184)</sup>

Comment: Neither `for…in`, `Object.keys` nor `Object.values` considers symbol properties anyway, so nothing changes for those

Comment: @Bergi You're right, I changed the wording, thanks. (This happens when I edit an old post without thinking much about what it says...)