# unable to see the property assigned by Object.defineProperty in the console

Tags: javascript

Why does logging an object that has a property assigned to it not show in the console?

```js
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
  value: 42,
  writable: false});


object1.property1 = 77;
// Throws an error in strict mode

console.log(object1);
// Expected output: {'property1': 42}

console.log(object1.property1)
```

Comment: What browser are you using (or are you referring to the stack-snippets console?)?

Comment: In Chrome it [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zU89.png) as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because the console you're using uses something like `JSON.stringify()` or `for...in` to create the logging display for its objects (for example, the stack-snippets console uses `for...in` to create its stringified object). The `JSON.stringify()` method and [many](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#traversing_object_properties) looping methods such as `for...in` will skip properties that aren't [enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean). By default, when using [`defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description) to create a new property, the property is automatically set as `enumerable: false`. Instead, if you define it explicitly as `true`, you'll see it appear as expected:

```js
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
  value: 42,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true // explicitly state that the property is enumerable
});


object1.property1 = 77;
// Throws an error in strict mode

console.log(object1);
// Expected output: {'property1': 42}

console.log(object1.property1)
```