# Cannot see property of Map object using Object.entries method

Tags: typescript

I am novice in Typescript but have more experience with C#. To learn some basics of the Typescript language, I wrote a function that displays the names of properties and their values for an object, a kind of analogue of JSON.stringify method.

```
export function writeData<T extends object>(data: T): string {
    let result: { key: string, value: any }[] =
        Object.entries(data).map(entry => ({ key: entry[0], value: entry[1] }));
    result.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.value instanceof Object) {
            entry.value = `{ ${writeData(entry.value)} }`;
        }
    })
    return result.map(d => `${d.key}: ${d.value}`).join(", ");
}
```

So when I use it with such example

```
let data = {
    id: 1,
    name: "outer",
    inner: {
        id: 1,
        name: "inner",
    }
}
console.log(writeData(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I see the following output which suits me just fine:

```
id: 1, name: outer, inner: { id: 1, name: inner }        - from writeData    
{"id":1,"name":"outer","inner":{"id":1,"name":"inner"}}  - from JSON.stringify
```

But when I use this function with following example I don't get size property of Map object in output. My output is just empty object. I suppose that I should see 'size' property - `{"size": 1}`. Could you please explain me why I don't have size property of Map object with my own function and also with JSON.stringify?

```
let data = {
    id: 1,
    name: "outer",
    inner: {
        id: 1,
        name: "inner",
    }
}
// console.log(writeData(data));
// console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

let mapData = new Map<string, any>();
mapData.set("data", data);

console.log(writeData(mapData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mapData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [`Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [the `JSON.stringify()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) only iterate over the [own, enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of objects.

*Own* properties must exist directly on an object and are not inherited from its [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) chain.

*Enumerable* properties are those marked with an  enumerable flag (see [What does enumerable mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17893718/2887218)); most normal properties set by `obj.prop = val` assignments are enumerable, but some are explicitly marked  not enumerable to avoid being included when iterating over objects. [Accessor properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#accessor_property) (such as those implemented as a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) are usually not enumerable.

---

The [`size` property of a `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) is an accessor property of `Map.prototype`, and therefore, given an instance of `Map`, the `size` property is neither own nor enumerable.  So it is not included in the results of `Object.entries()` or `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Now javascript seems even more difficult for me(( 
I need to assimilate your information