# Why would the ES6 class syntax console log differently than an ES5 class syntax?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, prototype, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to learn ECMAScript 6 more and inheritance a bit better.

**Question:** When I console log out `bob` vs `daisy` they differ. `bob` *logs* a prototype under `__proto__` and shows his constructor of `run:true;`. On the ES6 implementation `daisy` has no `__proto__` however, it still has `isRunning` accessible. Why?

[image]

```
var Man = (function(){
  "use strict";
  function Man() {
    this.run = true
  }

  Man.prototype.isRunning = function() {
    console.log('yesss imma run');
  };

  return Man;
})();

var bob = new Man();
console.log(bob);

class Woman {
  constructor(){
    this.run = true;
  }

  isRunning() {
    console.log('yess imma run');
  }
}

var daisy = new Woman();
console.log(daisy);
```

Comment: Is this really the right interpretation of `use strict` inside [a function definition?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)    I presume this is ecmascript-6 (ES6) code, but aren't you comparing ES6 strict vs non-strict, and not ES5 vs ES6 ?

Comment: I'm getting this behaviour on jsfiddle, codepen however is logging both with a `_proto_`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gryyWg

Comment: The behavior of the console is not standardized. It's completely implementation dependent.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense

Comment: Do a `console.dir(daisy)` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because methods defined in ES6 classes are **non enumerable**. In a **Man** object, **isRunning** is enumerable, but not in **Woman**. And Chrome has a specific way of handling the console log. Depending on the presence of enumerable properties or not will affect the display.

The difference in the console display is trivial, but it shows an interesting difference in the way classes are built with ES6 **Class**. To see it more clearly, you can try to either make Man **isRunning** non enumerable or Woman **isRunning** enumerable, it should give the same output in the console. Like this for non enumerable in Man:

```js
var Man = (function() {
     "use strict";

     function Man() {
       this.run = true
     }

     Object.defineProperty(Man.prototype, 'isRunning', {
       value: function() {
         console.log('yesss imma run');
       },
       enumerable: false
     });

     return Man;
   })();

   
   bob = new Man();
   console.log(bob);

   class Woman {
     constructor() {
       this.run = true;
     }

     isRunning() {
       console.log('yess imma run');
     }
   }

   daisy = new Woman();
   console.log(daisy);
```

Or enumerable in Woman:

```js
   var Man = (function() {
     "use strict";

     function Man() {
       this.run = true
     }

     Man.prototype.isRunning = function() {
       console.log('yesss imma run');
     };

     return Man;
   })();


   bob = new Man();
   console.log(bob);

   class Woman {
     constructor() {
       this.run = true;
     }

     isRunning() {
       console.log('yess imma run ');
     }
   }
   Object.defineProperty(Woman.prototype, 'isRunning', {
     enumerable: true
   });
   daisy = new Woman();
   console.log(daisy);
```

EDIT:

Note that initial drafts of ES6 had enumerable set to true by default, but it was changed, it's a design decision. You can see discussions leading to that decision here:
https://esdiscuss.org/topic/classes-and-enumerability

Basically, native prototypes usually have non enumerable methods, so it made sense to have the same behavior with user defined classes.

This decision was introduced in draft rev 32. 
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#february_2_2015_draft_rev_32

Comment: Might I ask a follow up as to why prototype methods are set to enumerable false when using ES6 class syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984533/what-are-the-benefits-of-making-properties-non-enumerable?rq=1