# Accessing API class names in global context

Tags: javascript

I am writing some ES/JS tooling.  In DevTools I can see lots of classes, e.g. ArrayBuffer. Yet when I try to extract such names from `window` global context, I can't see them. This snippet gives similar results in Chrome, FireFox and Opera.

[MWE on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th8r3woe/)

```
console.log('typeof window.ArrayBuffer:', 
        typeof window.ArrayBuffer);
console.log("window.hasOwnProperty('ArrayBuffer'):", 
        window.hasOwnProperty('ArrayBuffer'));

let c = 0;
for (let n in window) {
    // console.log(n);
    if (n == 'ArrayBuffer') {
        console.log('FOUND: ArrayBuffer');
    }
    c++;
}
console.log(c + ' attributes checked')
```

If I uncomment the `// console.log(n);` line, I can see the names of the attributes, but none of the classes.

How do I access those class (API) names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all properties (including non-enumerable properties except for those which use Symbol). Then loop through them to find the class name:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach((n) => {
    if (n === 'ArrayBuffer') {
        console.log('FOUND: ArrayBuffer');
    }
})
```

Comment: Went from 214 attributes found to 958.  Checked by printing all attributes found and it matches what DevTools shows.

Answer (score 4):

It's matter of Object's [Enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

[for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (as well as Object.keys/values/entries) does **not** account for non enumerable properties:

```js
window.hasOwnProperty('ArrayBuffer');       // true
window.propertyIsEnumerable('ArrayBuffer'); // false
// Therefore will not show up in for-in loop
```

To create a non-enumerable object property, an example is by using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for (const prop in obj) console.log(obj[prop]); // 1 2 3

Object.defineProperty(obj, "d", {
  value: 4,
  // enumerable: false,      // defaults to false!!
  // set to true to make it enumerable
});

for (const prop in obj) console.log(obj[prop]); //  1 2 3 (no 4 visible)

// Same goes for iterating using Object.keys and Object.values:
console.log(...Object.values(obj)) // 1 2 3 (no 4 visible)
```

To get all the properties of an Object you might use instead [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```js
const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

console.log(props.includes('ArrayBuffer'));                    // true
console.log(props.some(pr => pr === 'ArrayBuffer'));           // true
console.log(props.findIndex(pr => pr === 'ArrayBuffer') > -1); // true

console.log(props.length);                   // 963
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(window).length); // 963

// See them all:
console.log(props);

// Loop them all:
// props.forEach(pr => console.log(pr));
```

Keep in mind that for...in loops only **enumerable properties** - with the exception of Symbols.

To get an Array ot the Object's own-property keys with Symbols use [Reflect.ownKeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)

> The Reflect.ownKeys method returns an array of the target object's own property keys. Its return value is equivalent to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(target))`

**Additional read:**

- [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)
- [What are the benefits of non-enumerable Object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14984533/383904)

Comment: I would like to see all the properties of window, e,g, Animation, Audio. ArrayBuffer is just one example. BTW:  window.propertyIsEnumerable('window');  // true.

Comment: @CyberFonic see the last example `props.forEach(pr => console.log(pr));` (not appropriate for Stack Snippets since there's a load of properties that do not fit into the Stack Snippet console)

Comment: @CyberFonic regarding your question about `"window" // true`... since it's enumerable **will shop up** using *for...in*: `for(p in window) {if(p=="window") console.log(p);} // "window"` -- therefore it's enumerable: `window.propertyIsEnumerable('window'); // true`. Also, if it might interest you: for the case `window.window.window.window` etc... returning Window - refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window